# How can I use drush_invoke() in my code called from hook_update_N()`?

Tags: 7, drush

I need to do a few things which could be easily made with Drush commands, but I need to achieve them through PHP code inside my module, on an `hook_update_N()`.

It seems to me that I need to use `drush_invoke()` but it doesn't currently exists when I tested in a devel block. I searched here and there how to include (safely) this function, but I had no luck on that.

I guess it is simple and my question could sound silly.

How can I use `drush_invoke()` in my code called from `hook_update_N()`?

Comment: The [`drush_invoke()` API docs](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/includes%21command.inc/function/drush_invoke/8.0.x) has a "calls to" section that you can reference in the Drush codebase to demonstrate how the function is used.

Comment: My code? What code? Please update your question to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My tags says it is for Drupal 7. I will update my question to be more explicit on this.

Comment: Notice that _What code?_ is not asking which Drupal version you are using, but which code you are using.